# Wordpress: automatically create a category inside custom taxonomy from authors name

Tags: php, wordpress

On my website different authors can write an article. I'm trying to create a filter so people can include/ exclude specific authors from a query.

To do this, i want to be able to automatically create categories inside a custom taxonomy named 'team'. That way I can query the categories inside the filter.

I know it is possible to auto create categories from post titles (see stackoverflow [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117070/automatically-save-custom-post-type-title-as-a-category)). But how can I do this for every author created?

So far i've build this, but no category is created when creating or saving an author.

```
// create cat from author
add_action('save_post', 'add_author_as_category');

function add_author_as_category($postid)
{
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;
    $post = get_post($postid);
    if ($post->post_type == 'team') { // change 'post' to any cpt you want to target

        $author_id = $post->post_author;
        $theAuthor = the_author_meta('user_nicename', $author_id);

        $term = get_term_by('slug', $theAuthor, 'team');

        if (empty($term)) {
            $add = wp_insert_term($theAuthor, 'team', array('slug' => $theAuthor));
            if (is_array($add) && isset($add['term_id'])) {
                wp_set_object_terms($postid, $add['term_id'], 'team', true);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to adapt the function from the question you linked? Doesn't it work? Is there an error message?

Comment: I have no idea where to start, that's the problem ;)

Comment: Have you read the answer you linked? Do you understand the code? Stack Overflow is not a coding service. Try it yourself. If you have problems, SO is ready and happy to help.

Comment: Wow thanks for mentioning SO is not a coding service.

Comment: Have an upvote for posting your code! I can't really help you though, I'm afraid. But it seems your code targets saving a post, not saving an author. `$post->post_type == 'team'` also seems questionable.